# Cant Display AlertView or PopOver

Tags: iphone, dictionary, uialertview, uipopovercontroller, cloudmade

I am using [cloudmade](http://cloudmade.com/) map for displaying map even in offline mode. My issue is I am not able to display UIPopoverController in map view. Also I tried to display alert view over it. It does not displayed. I tried this code.

```
MyViewController *mvc=[[MyViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"MyViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
UIPopoverController *popover=[[UIPopoverController alloc]initWithContentViewController:mvc];


NSLog(@"%f",marker.frame.size.width);
[popover presentPopoverFromRect:marker.frame inView:mapView permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know why it happens, but solved the problem by defining UIPopoverController in .h 
and setting property

```
 @property(nonatomic,retain) popover;
```

Then in .m

```
MyViewController *mvc=[[MyViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"MyViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
UIPopoverController *mypopover=[[UIPopoverController alloc]initWithContentViewController:mvc];


self.popover=myPopover;
[self.popover presentPopoverFromRect:marker.frame inView:mapView permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];
```

Even though I am using ARC (not used that feature before) and not releasing popover anywhere, I got error message like '-[UIPopoverController dealloc] reached while popover is still visible.' .